# TextMate Haskell Plugin

Tags: haskell, textmate, textmatebundles

I am a big fan of textmate, and have recently had to start using Haskell for school. I was wondering if anyone knows where I can find the haskell bundle for textmate. I have tried the directions in the textmate documentation, and checked the svn for the file (haskell.tembundle), but I can't seem to find it anywhere. Does anyone know where I can find it? Otherwise, any other way to get Haskell syntax highlighting in textmate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On GitHub: https://github.com/textmate/haskell.tmbundle

Comment: Thanks man, I tried downloading that, but it came down as a zipped folder, it never hit me to rename it .tmbundle. Loving this colourful programming1